# SonarLint: Declaration of unchecked exceptions

Tags: java, exception, sonarlint

Default ruleset of SonarLint says me that I shouldnot declare an unchecked exception (in my case `NoSuchElementException`) in a method signature. I know, that it's not required by Java, but in my case I want to warn user that he/she can get this exception when he/she uses my method incorrect. I don't want to use a checked exception, because this method is mostly (99%) used correct. The documentation for the exception is, of course, also provided, but it can be outside of the visible range of tooltip in IDE. So I don't understand why I shouldn't (or it's not recomended to) declare unchecked exception in a method signature?